# row update in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql

I'm working on a MVVM application and I'm trying to make an update to an object of my database from the viewmodel.

I'm trying to update a boolean `IsDisplayed` which is binded to a toggle switch in two-way mode. But in the end the object is not updated... What is wrong?

This is the method who is called when I want to save the boolean state:

```
public static void UpdateIsDisplayedInServices(List<ECList> lists)
{
    ECList listToUpdate;

    foreach (ECList list in lists)
    {
        listToUpdate = GetECList(list.DatabaseId);

        listToUpdate = list;     // I also tried listToUpdate.IsDiplayed = list.IsDiplayed
        ECContextManager.Context.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I made a unit test to expose the problem.

```
[TestMethod]
public void _1DeactivateService()
{
    bool newBool = false;

    ECContextManager.Dispose();

    ECList service = ECListManager.GetECList(2);

    // IsDiplayed is true by default
    service.IsDisplayed = newBool;
    service.Subtitle = "test";

    ECContextManager.Context.SubmitChanges();
    ECContextManager.Dispose();

    ECList service2 = ECListManager.GetECList(2);

    if (newBool)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(service2.IsDisplayed);
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(service2.IsDisplayed);
    }
}
```

at the end `service2` has the subtitle "test" but the IsDiplayed value is still to "true"...

Comment: You need to provide some more info.  Is the databinding working?

Comment: yes, the databinding works. I maybe have a problem with the database context not beeing disposed

Comment: I just updated my original post, I hope the informations are more helpfull